# PhpMyAdmin SQL Find and replace not working with url that includes escape characters

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress, phpmyadmin

my `wp_postmeta` table includes a lot of URLs under the meta_value column which read like:

```
http:\/\/somename.somehost.com\/~someuser\/sites\/example.com\/
```

I'd like to change the whole thing to simply `https:\/\/example.com\/`

1. How do I do that using Find and replace in PhpMyAdmin?
   OR if not possible >> How do I do that with a query?
2. Are the escape backslashes necessary with the new desired URL as well?

Thanks for any advice :-)

Comment: anyone? Would appreciate any help I can get :-)

Answer (score 0):

`wp_postmeta` should not contain any backslashes (escape characters) unless you really want that character.  A URL looks like

```
https://example.com/
```

not

```
https:\/\/example.com\/
```

Are you escaping forward-slash because of some app that needs them escaped?

To remove existing single backslashes, first test via:

```
SELECT REPLACE(meta_value, '\\\\/', '/')
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_value LIKE 'http%\\\\/%`
    LIMIT 5;    -- just check a few
```

If that fails, change to only `\\/` and retest.  Similarly change the update below.

Then do something like

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '\\\\/', '/')
    WHERE meta_value LIKE 'http%\\\\/%`;
```

Comment: Nope - that's just the way it is right now, which had me assume that's how it's supposed to be :-)

Comment: Thank for that tho... Any idea over how to actually use the find replace then..? My understanding is that I should use another backslash for each existing one in order to replace it? Do I need to find "https:\\/\\/example.com\\/" and then replace it with just "https://example.com/" ?

Comment: @LiorTalmor - OK, I added the `REPLACE`.